Could the use of the expression "joints" be misinterpreted in this text?
The use of the expression "joints" in the text below (and considering that it actually makes sense) makes it clear that it is referring to the low quality of the places in which the band plays, or it could somehow be confused with an allusion to illicit drugs?
I'm not going to lie to you and say that our band is a huge success and that we play in the best clubs in town. Your brother knows exactly the kind of joints we use to get.

The previous sentence mentions best clubs in town, and hence
‘joints’ is understood to take sense 6 in Collins Dictionary:

You can refer to a cheap place where people go for some form of entertainment as a joint.

Here we are comparing two types of places.
There’re no mentions of drugs in the example, and hence I won’t overthink and take sense 7 in the same dictionary:

A joint is a cigarette which contains cannabis or marijuana.

The likelihood of misinterpretation isn’t high.
